# php: pushing to an array that may or may not exist

Tags: php, arrays, declaration, push

I want to create an array with a message.

```
$myArray = array('my message');
```

But using this code, `myArray` will get overwritten if it already existed.

If I use `array_push`, it has to already exist.

```
$myArray = array(); // <-- has to be declared first.
array_push($myArray, 'my message');
```

Otherwise, it will bink.

Is there a way to make the second example above work, without first clearing `$myArray = array();`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check if the array exists first, and if it doesn't, create it...then add the element, knowing that the array will surely be defined before hand :

```
if (!isset($myArray)) {
    $myArray = array();
}

array_push($myArray, 'my message');
```

Comment: snap ... except the new bit, which I don't think works in php

Comment: heh yea...that's what happens when you have one too many languages roaming in your head :-)

Answer (score 37):

Here:

```
$myArray[] = 'my message';
```

$myArray have to be an array or not set. If it holds a value which is a string, integer or object that doesn't implement arrayaccess, it will fail.

Comment: It's weird, but it's true. PHP won't trigger any error/warning/notice on that.

Comment: ...an incredibly useful feature (for me at least)

Answer (score 3):

You should use is_array(), not isset.
Usefull if myArray is being set from a function that returns an array or a string (-1 on error for example)

This will prevent errors if myArray is declared as a not an array somewhere else.

```
if(is_array($myArray))
{
   array_push($myArray,'my message');
}
else
{
   $myArray = array("my message");
}
```

Comment: You correctly mention is_array, but use non-existent function array_exists.

Comment: Doh! TCL was getting in the way :P

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($myArray) {
  array_push($myArray, 'my message');
}
else {
  $myArray = array('my message');
}
```

Comment: You should test if a var holds an array with isset and is_array.

Comment: Why *and*? is_array() should be enough. It can hardly be an array if it is not set.

Comment: Yes, my bad wording. I meant either. Should have used or.

Answer (score 0):

OIS' way will work.

Or

```
if (!isset($myArray)) 
    $myArray=array();
array_push($myArray, 'message');
```