# Codeigniter Pagination Show Number of Results & Page

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination, codeigniter-3

I am using Codeigniter 3 and have a simple PHP application.

Using the pagination class I would like to display the following at the top of each of my pages;

> Showing x to y of z results

Where;

```
x = start row
y - end row
z = total rows

`Showing 1 to 10 of 5213 results.`
`Showing 11 to 20 of 5213 results.`
`etc`
```

I am able to retrieve the total rows using the `$config['total_rows']` variable. Not sure about the rest though.

My items.php controller looks like this;

```
    public function index() {
        $config['base_url'] = '/items/index';
        $config['use_page_numbers'] = FALSE; 
        $config['reuse_query_string'] = TRUE;
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->get('item')->num_rows();
        $config['per_page'] = 10;
        $config['num_links'] = 10;
        $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div><ul class="pagination">';
        $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul></div><!--pagination-->';
        $config['first_link'] = '&laquo; First';
        $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev page">';
        $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['last_link'] = 'Last &raquo;';
        $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li class="next page">';
        $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['next_link'] = 'Next &rarr;';
        $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li class="next page">';
        $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['prev_link'] = '&larr; Previous';
        $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev page">';
        $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="">';
        $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
        $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li class="page">';
        $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['anchor_class'] = 'follow_link';
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $data = array(
        'items' => $this->items_model->itemList()
        );

        $this->load->view('item_list', $data);
    }
```

My URLs are in the following format;

```
items/index    // displays results 1-10
items/index/10 // displays results 11-20
items/index/20 // displays results 21-30
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I made an answer but didn't pay attention of url formats, I made it like those are 1, 2, 3 etc.

Comment: Are you getting 1-10 results when you are on `items/index/10` page?

Comment: Set, check now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$data['z'] = $config['total_rows'];

$data['x'] = (int)$this->uri->segment(3) + 1;

if ($this->uri->segment(3) + $config['per_page'] > $config['total_rows']) {
    $data['y'] = $config['total_rows'];
} else {
    $data['y'] = (int)$this->uri->segment(3) + $config['per_page'];
}
```

Also, you can make one check before loading view if requested page is in range and if it is not you should redirect visitor to first or last page as per your requirement.

Comment: This code should go into controller. It is meant to work that way. Should be placed just before view load line. All values x, y, z will be available in view through `$data` array passed. You already did it. Or I am not sure what is asked: can you clarify?

Comment: Maybe it is up to separated view files. I.E if you have different partial files but want to include variables there too. I am just guessing this. To avoid that case there is other way of injecting data into view. `$this->load->vars($data);$this->load->view('item_list');`. This way data that have been passed from controller would be available to all view files that are included in single request.

Comment: Also, you have to put snippet I provided AFTER `$data = array('items' => $this->items_model->itemList());`. Otherwise you are overwriting array.

Comment: That's exactly what it was - I had placed the code *before* `$data = array('items' => $this->items_model->itemList());`. I had no idea this would make a difference?! Thank you so much @Tpojka

Comment: Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/351017/php-pushing-to-an-array-that-may-or-may-not-exist).

#SOreadyToHelp Happy coding. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Place below code in your controller below pagination function:-

```
$start= (int)$this->uri->segment(3) * $config['per_page']+1;
$end = ($this->uri->segment(3) == floor($config['total_rows']/ $config['per_page']))? $config['total_rows'] : (int)$this->uri->segment(3) * $config['per_page'] + $config['per_page'];

$data['result_count']= "Showing ".$start." - ".$end." of ".$config['total_rows']." Results";
```

on your view :-

```
<?php echo $result_count;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised there's no mention of extending the Pagination library? Much more elegant, and can be added to with additional functionality if needed.

**application/libraries/MY_Pagination.php**

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Pagination extends CI_Pagination
{
    /**
     * Total number of items
     *
     * @var int
     */
    protected $total_rows = 0;

    public function __construct($params = array())
    {
        parent::__construct($params);
    }

    public function get_total_rows(): int
    {
        return $this->total_rows;
    }
}
```